# I can not access my images on media folder, Django project

Tags: django, permissions, ubuntu-18.04

In my media folder I have some images, usually I can access them as domain/images/image1.jpg. But now it is not working and the browser is showing me this error: "You don't have permission to access /media/image1.jpg on this server.".

This are the perrmissions for the media folder:

`drwxrwxr-x  3 admin www-data 4096 Jan 29 11:36 media`

And here are my settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' 
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o775
```

What I am doing wrong?